# How can I log username and email address with StofDoctrineBundle?

Tags: symfony, logging, bundle, yaml, add-on

I am running a Symfony2 app with Symfony2 and I'm using the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) to manage my users.

Now I implemented the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to use the loggable extensions. Unfortunately I cannot log the `username` and the `email`. If I try to activate logging via YML:

```
Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  gedmo:
    loggable: true
  fields:
    id:
      ...
    username:
      type: string
      gedmo:
        - versioned
    email:
      type: string
      gedmo:
        - versioned
```

I get a

> Duplicate definition of column 'username' on entity in a field or discriminator column mapping.

So I tried to activate the logging in annotations (note that I define all my other entities via YML):

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    ...
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    protected $email;
```

But: Nothing happens. All other properties of my `User` are logged, but `username` and `email` are not.

What do I have to change in order to activate logging for those both properties? Or is this an interdependency between the FOSUserBundle and the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle that I cannot influence?

Comment: You have duplicated field `username`. You may have to put `email` there.

Comment: Ah, no sorry. That was just in this sniplet. I got it correct in my code. I updated, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this configuration?:

```
   //app/config/config.yml
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
      auto_mapping: true
      mappings:
       translatable:
          type: annotation
          alias: Gedmo
          prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
          dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
       loggable:
          type: annotation
          alias: Gedmo
          prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
          dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
       tree:
          type: annotation
          alias: Gedmo
          prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
          dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
       sluggable:
          type: annotation
          alias: Gedmo
          prefix: Gedmo\Sluggable\Entity
          dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
```

Comment: Yes, as written in my question, loggable works, but not on username and email.